# Quadratic Forms and Newton's Method

Tags: algorithms, optimization, recursive-algorithms

> Consider the function $f(x,y) = 5x^2 + 5y^2 -xy -11x +11y +11$.  Consider applying Newton's Method for minimizing $f$.  How many iterations are needed to reach the global minimum point?  Why should we expect this answer?

The above is paraphrased from a past test.  Does anyone know how to approach this kind of question?

Comment: Hint: it's a convex quadratic function, so there is not much to iterate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm recalling the relevant facts properly, this question is testing your basic knowledge about how Newton's method works. If you can state the idea behind Newton's method or explain what it calculates, then the answer to the quoted question follows almost immediately.

I believe the only two approaches here, then, are:

- Know your stuff
- Do some experimental calculations in hopes it will reveal the answer to you

---

The idea behind Newton's method for optimizing a function is, at each iteration, to approximate the function with a quadratic, and then solve for the minimum of the quadratic. So when the function you're trying to optimize is already quadratic....

Comment: Then clearly I do not know my stuff.  Newton's method converges with order 2 so I would expect that this problem also converges with order 2, as we would expect.  I feel like this is too naive though.

Comment: In part I am trying to reconcile that image of Newton's method with the method displayed visually here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method

Comment: Ah; Newton has *two* methods. One of them is for finding roots of equations (which uses the linear approximation), and the other one is for minimizing functions: see the "Newton's method in optimization link" disambiguation at the top of your link.

Comment: Ah, now it's clear why they didn't mesh.  So clearly then as you mentioned it will converge in one step.  How many steps will it take in general?  How does this fit with order and rate of convergence?  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Alas, it's been so long since I've actually *used* Newton's method in optimization that really, I'd have to consult wikipedia to be confident about anything. Or try to rederive it from scratch, I suppose.